# Can I carry gold with me from Turkey to Spain without paying taxes?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, spain, eu, taxes

I am planning to carry less then 200 grams of gold with me in a flight from Turkey to Madrid. I wonder if this is okay and if I have to pay some taxes.

Comment: What is the form of the gold (coins, bar, jewelry)?

Comment: This seems to be the official spanish customs site in english which should be used as your primary source to answer your question. https://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/en_gb/Inicio/La_Agencia_Tributaria/Aduanas_e_Impuestos_Especiales/_Presentacion/La_Aduana_espanola/La_Aduana_espanola.shtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bringing 10000 EUR in cash or equivalent -- which gold is -- requires a declaration. It's all fine and there's no VAT on gold but you need to declare. You might be even below that: today a gram is 44.45 EUR which means 200g is a bit below 9000 EUR. So: you should be fine. If gold surges between now and when you enter the EU you will need to declare.

Comment: If it is in the shape of jewelry or other items, the value can be more than gold price.

Comment: Then sharing it among several family members should be fine, right?

Comment: Now you are scheming to skirt the rules. _Never_ do that.